# How to add animation to a bootstrap 4 card on hover?

Tags: html, css

I have a card to which I would like to apply some basic animation like - zoom in effect and border color change on hover. I have tried several methods but nothing is working for me. Many similar questions have been asked before, and I tried a few but not getting satisfactory result.

Below is my code -

HTML

```
<div class="container">
<a class=" text-decoration-none " href="">
<div class="card">
<img class="icon" src=""/>
<div class="card-text">
AlphaBetaGamma
</div>
<div class="d-flex align-items-center justify-content-end">
<span class="read-more">READ MORE</span>
<i class="fas fa-arrow-circle-right"></i>
</div>
</div>
</a>
</div>
```

CSS-

```
.card .read-more:hover{
    font-size: 14px;
}

.card :hover{
    box-shadow: 8px 8px 8px blue;
}
```

The box shadow part is not working for some reason. I would also like the text on the card to grow a little when the card zooms and a blue shadow should add.

How can I achieve this ?

Comment: Can you add a minimal reproducible example in the form of a snippet?

Comment: Please try to add your implementation.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The first thing to do is check whether you've imported Bootstrap 4 correctly and that you've imported all required files (CSS, JS, jQuery and Popper)
It's best to follow the steps from their official docs - https://getbootstrap.com/

1. The box-shadow code seems to be working.
2. For a zoom effect you can use `transform: scale(scale_value)` So first you set a transition property to your read-more class and then on hover you scale it by adding a transform property.

Here's a codepen with your code demonstrating how you can do this:

https://codepen.io/jaimish11/pen/oNbrMZW

Answer (score 9):

For smooth transitional effects, add 'transition' to the element you'd like to target. Then in the hover selector, change the dimensions and it should happen with a smoother transition.

Same with color changes etc.. This is just one of the ways.

```css
.card .read-more:hover{
    font-size: 14px;
}

.card:hover{
    box-shadow: 8px 8px 8px blue;
    transform:scale(1.2);
}

.card{
  height:200px;
  width:200px;
  border:1px solid black;
  transition:.3s;
  margin: 3rem;
}
```

```html
    <div class="container">
      <a class=" text-decoration-none " href="">
        <div class="card m-5">
          <img class="icon" src=""/>
          <div class="card-text">
          AlphaBetaGamma
          </div>
          <div class="d-flex align-items-center justify-content-end">
            <span class="read-more">READ MORE</span>
            <i class="fas fa-arrow-circle-right"></i>
          </div>
        </div>
      </a>
   </div>
```

Answer (score 5):

I think this will get the desired result that you want.

```css
.card:hover{
    box-shadow: 8px 8px 5px blue;    
    transform: scale(1.1);

}
```

```html
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-9aIt2nRpC12Uk9gS9baDl411NQApFmC26EwAOH8WgZl5MYYxFfc+NcPb1dKGj7Sk" crossorigin="anonymous">

</head>
<body>
<a href="..." class=" text-decoration-none">
<div class="card m-5" style="width: 18rem;">
  <!-- Added a sample image for visualisation-->
  <img src="https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn%3AANd9GcRFd82s5apuZZXe_Hey_n73oahb7JEcw7u-qA&usqp=CAU" class="card-img-top" alt="...">
  <div class="card-body">
    <div class="card-text">
          AlphaBetaGamma
    </div>
    <div class="d-flex align-items-center justify-content-end">
            <span class="read-more">READ MORE</span>
            <i class="fas fa-arrow-circle-right"></i>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
</a>
</body>
```

Comment: Thank you for providing the solution ! it works as desired.